# Custom UITableViewCell, UITableView and allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, multipleselection

I have a problem using **iOS 5** new functionality to select multiple cells during editing mode.
The application structure is the following:

```
-> UIViewController
---> UITableView
----> CustomUITableViewCell
```

where `UIViewController` is both the delegate and the data source for the `UITableView` (I'm using an `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` for requirement reasons and I cannot change it). Cells are loaded into the `UITableView` like the following code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCellXib" owner:self options:nil];     
        cell = self.customTableViewCellOutlet;    
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // configure the cell with data
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];    

    return cell;
}
```

The cell interface has been created from a xib file. In particular, I've created a new xib file where the superview consists of a `UITableViewCell` element. To provide customization, I set the type for that element as `CustomUITableViewCell`, where `CustomUITableViewCell` extends `UITableViewCell`.

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

// do stuff here

@end
```

The code works well. In the table custom cells are displayed. Now, during application execution I set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES` and I enter the edit mode for the `UITableView`. It seems working. In fact, alongside of each cell an empty circle appears. The problem is that when I select a row the empty circle doesn't change its state. In theory, the circle has to change from empty to red checkmark and viceversa. It seems that circle remains above the `contentView` for the cell.

I've made a lot of experiments. I've also checked also that following method.

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

and it gets updated during selection in editing mode. It displays the right selected cells.

The thing that it's not so clear to me is that when I try to work without a custom cell, only with `UITableViewCell`, the circle updates its state correctly.

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested in, I've found a valid solution to fix the previous problem.
The problem is that when selection style is `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` red checkmarks in editing mode aren't displayed correctly. The solution is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` and ovverride some methods. I'm using `awakeFromNib` because my cell has been created through xib. To reach the solution I've followed these two stackoverflow topics:

1. [multi-select-table-view-cell-and-no-selection-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890900/multi-select-table-view-cell-and-no-selection-style)
2. [uitableviewcell-how-to-prevent-blue-selection-background-w-o-borking-isselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899862/uitableviewcell-how-to-prevent-blue-selection-background-w-o-borking-isselected)

Here the code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row_normal"]] autorelease];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row_selected"]] autorelease];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(selected && !self.isEditing)
    {

        return;
    }        

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

- (void)setHighlighted: (BOOL)highlighted animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    // don't highlight
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
```

Hope it helps.