# Custom edit of cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, edit, cells

Could you please help me. I need to perform editing cells. The editing should look like:
when I press a barButtonItem (the right one on the nav bar) the content of cells should slightly move to the right and checkboxes should appear. The user should be able to select several cells and commit editing by clicking on the same navButton. 
I've tried to use standard editing but I can't figure out how:
- to select multiple cells and only then commit editing
- how to set commit action to navButton but not to red delete button which appears next to each selected cell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101810/custom-uitableviewcell-uitableview-and-allowsmultipleselectionduringediting   visit this refence..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-selection is regarded as one of the editing style. Therefore, to make a cell multi-selectable, implement this in your UITableViewDelegate:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  ...
  return 3;
}
```

The "3" here means multiselection. The result is like this:

[image]

To get the selected rows, call the

```
-indexPathsForSelectedRows method on the table view.
NSArray* selectedRows = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

If you dislike the red check mark, you can use the undocumented multiselectCheckmarkColor property to change it. Unfortunately, it has to be applied on the whole table.

```
tableView.multiselectCheckmarkColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

The light blue background color cannot be changed unless you subclass or categorize

```
UITableViewCell and override the -_multiselectBackgroundColor method, like this:
-(UIColor*)_multiselectBackgroundColor { return [UIColor yellowColor]; }
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need. Could you also answer how to properly layout the custom views(labels, buttons, imgViews etc) which lay on my cell when I press edit? (Now when I press edit some views are moving relatively to the cell view) But I need that content just being compressed and do not move behind the visible bounds.

Comment: I am busy right now with some work will give you and by tomorrow because I have some work out on your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Nit's answer has a bug.

The code

```
tableView.multiselectCheckmarkColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

should be written like this:

```
[tableView setValue:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:@"multiselectCheckmarkColor"];
```

I tried this on Xcode 4.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant, note that on iOS 7+ you can simply use the tintColor property of the UITableView - this sets the checkmark colour.