# multiple selection in grouped tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I am working with grouped tableview with multiple sections. 
and I have to implement the functionality of multiple selection on didselectrow at indexpath
method. my code is as follows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

which allows me to select multiple cells
but when I scroll my tableview at that time my selection disappears.

Comment: follow this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Dude, set cell.accessoryType doesn't do any real selection for you. It is just your ui. And during your scroll, the memory used to populate your cells got reclaimed by the system when scrolled out of the screen. Take a look at the link Narayana give you and follow apple's sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection goes off when you scroll because it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath and there you have not handle selection.

To avoid this problem you can do as follows:
In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can save index path of selected row as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        //remove index path
        [selectedIndexPathArray removeObject:path];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [selectedIndexPathArray addObject:path];
    }
}
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check whether cell is selected or not.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //If selectedIndexPathArray contains current index path then display checkmark.
    if([selectedIndexPathArray containsObject:indexPath])
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    if (self.tableView.isEditing) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleMultiSelect;
}

-(IBAction) switchEditing {
    [self.tableView setEditing:![self.tableView isEditing]];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // force reload to reset selection style
}
```

Hope this helps solving your problem.([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890900/multi-select-table-view-cell-and-no-selection-style))

Answer (score 0):

Your selection disapear cause the method `CellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called at scroll.
You need to set the accessory again.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    // here
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this  issue  because you are not tracking your row selections.When the callback method **cellForRowAtIndexPath** gets called for the rows that had disappeared/(scrolled up/down) the cell object no longer remembers whether it was selected or not. (reason those selections are disappearing)

I would suggest you to use a collection like **NSMutableArray/NSArray** to track the selected rows.
You can use either of these approaches.

This would be a quick working fix:
Add/Remove the index path object in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** based on the users selection
and then based on the contents of that array u can toggle the value of cell.accessoryType for the corresponding cell.

Ideally,you can use a data bean/model with some boolean member  called **selected** and u can update its value based on the selection made.Then instead of  simply adding those index path u can add those meaningful data bean objects  onto your array and get the  selections back from the **selected** property of the bean.This approach would help u in getting back the row selections  even if the user kills and restarts  the app **provided u persist the bean objects in database/archive**..(But it all depends on ur use case and requirements!)

Hope this helped!